# loop over all custom taxonomies for current custom post type and their values

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

What I want to do:

I have four custom post types. I only want to use one, which I can do like this: `$current_posttype = get_post_type( $post->ID ); // get current post type`
.

Next up, I want to loop through all the custom taxonomies that are attached to that custom post type. So, for example:

```
custom post type: movies
custom taxonomy 1: genre
custom taxonomy 2: rating
custom taxonomy 3: year
and so on..
```

I want to output the following (for the current post):

```
genre: Western
rating: 4
year: 2000
```

What I do know is that I can use the following code to output all terms of a custom taxonomy.

```
// Get terms for post
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'genre' );

 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
     // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 if ( $term->name != null ) {
 ?></br><?php print $term->name ;
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 }
 else {
 }
  unset($term);
} }
```

What I don't know is how to loop over this, with a foreach loop. I can't figure it out. Any help or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a loop to retrieve the taxonomies:

```
foreach( array('genre', 'rating', 'year') as $taxo ){
  #loop over each taxonomy
  $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , $taxo );

  if( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo $taxo . ': ';
    $myterm = array();
    #get list of term names
    foreach($terms as $term){
      $myterm[] = $term->name;
    }

   #display comma separated list of terms
   echo implode(',', $myterm) . '<br />';
  }

}
```

**Functions used:**

[get_the_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms),
[implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is [`get_object_taxonomies`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies).

```
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $current_posttype );
foreach ( (array) $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) { 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
    ...
}
```